# JAR file versions

Tags: jar, versioning

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 for C# and Eclipse 20120216-1857 for Java 1.6.37 to build a web app. Each of my Java projects contain bin and src directories, along with .project, *.classpath*, and *build.xml* files. I would like to version each of these JAR files with something like 2.1.1.1 and be able to see these versions at a glance, much like C# DLLs with version specified in the assembly.cs file and viewable in the file properties in Windows Explorer.

I've looked at other posts here and tried things such as a property `name="version" value="2.1.1.1"` in *build.xml*, `<version>2.1.1.1</version>` in .project and a single line `key="Version" value="2.1.1.1"` or `Specification-Version: 2.1.1.1` in a *manifest.txt* file that is part of the project in Eclipse. Being very new to Java (again - haven't done Java in 15 years) I think I'm grasping at straws and trying things that look like they might work from posts here on StackOverflow and other Googled sites, but I am not sure if anything is working because I don't see a Version attribute in the JAR file's properties nor in the MANIFEST.MF file that is part of the JAR file when it's opened with WinZip.

The build process is done with Nant and I'm not using Maven or Hudson, both of which I know about only through searches for my versioning issue today. So I'm at a loss here trying to figure out something that is probably quite easy to do, but I'm not sure how to find it. Any suggestions and/or solutions are greatly appreciated.